# can i use smart watch sim through locked iphone (different sim networks)?

Tags: ios, iphone, sony-smartwatch

If I have a locked sim iPhone connected (Bluetooth pairing) to smart watch (Android) which has another network sim, Can I call or answer the smart watch calls through the iPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it if you're locked out of your phone but not once you're locked out of the network.

Comment: sorry couldn't understand can explain more ?

Comment: You need to get your network of the sim unlocked first in order to attend calls on your smartwatch because if you dont have an active network you wouldn't be able to receive the calls in the first place. I hope this answers your question.